# Vue i18n format USD currency

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-i18n

When I display my currency in USD the output is always in the format
`USD$500.00`.

I am trying to remove the USD prefix from the start.

This is my numberFormats config:

```
numberFormats: {
    'en': {
        currency: {
            style: 'currency', currency: 'GBP'
        }
    },
    'us': {
        currency: {
            style: 'currency',
            currency: 'USD',
            currencyDisplay: 'symbol'
        }       
    }
}
```

I display the currency by doing `{{ $n(500, 'currency') }}`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the format `en-US` to specify the configuration.

As covered [in the docs](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/number.html), Vue I18n uses [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) to format numbers which relies on [ISO 4217 currency codes](https://www.currency-iso.org/en/home/tables/table-a1.html).

```js
const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: 'en-US',
  numberFormats: {
    'en-US': {
      currency: {
        style: 'currency',
        currency: 'USD',
        currencyDisplay: 'symbol'
      }
    }
  },
})

new Vue({
  i18n
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{ $n(500, 'currency') }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change symbole by narrowSymbol like this :

```
numberFormats: {
    'en': {
        currency: {
            style: 'currency', currency: 'GBP'
        }
    },
    'us': {
        currency: {
            style: 'currency',
            currency: 'USD',
            currencyDisplay: 'narrowSymbol'
        }       
    }
}
```